# How can I combine a tuple with n elements with a string into a list?

Tags: terraform

For my AWS Backup selection I am trying to add both an EFS file system and two RDS instances into my backup selection.

```
resource "aws_backup_selection" "backup" {
  name         = "${var.name}-backup-selection"
  iam_role_arn = aws_iam_role.backup.arn
  plan_id      = aws_backup_plan.backup.id

  resources = [  
    concat([aws_efs_file_system.files.arn], aws_rds_cluster_instance.cluster_instances.*.arn)
  ]

}
```

The shown "concat" is one of the variants I already tried with mixed error messages. This one gives me this:

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on backup.tf line 51, in resource "aws_backup_selection" "backup":
  51:   resources = [  
  52:     concat([aws_efs_file_system.files.arn], aws_rds_cluster_instance.cluster_instances.*.arn)
  53:   ]
    |----------------
    | aws_efs_file_system.files.arn is "arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:eu-central-1:xxx:file-system/fs-xxx"
    | aws_rds_cluster_instance.cluster_instances is tuple with 2 elements

Inappropriate value for attribute "resources": element 0: string required.
```

How can I combine both the ARN string and the list of two instances into the required list format for the resources element?

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't it what you need: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/tolist.html ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since concat returns a list, you can assign it directly to resources without the additional brackets:

```
resource "aws_backup_selection" "backup" {
  name         = "${var.name}-backup-selection"
  iam_role_arn = aws_iam_role.backup.arn
  plan_id      = aws_backup_plan.backup.id

  resources =
    concat([aws_efs_file_system.files.arn], aws_rds_cluster_instance.cluster_instances[*].arn)
}
```

The additional brackets turn the list result of concat into a list of lists, which is not what you want here.

I have also converted `aws_rds_cluster_instance.cluster_instances.*.arn` to `aws_rds_cluster_instance.cluster_instances[*].arn` since [legacy (attribute-only) splat expressions are deprecated][1].

[1]: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#legacy-attribute-only-splat-expressions l